# Create a bootable Ghost CD from a HDD

Tags: hard-drive, bootable-media, norton-ghost, pata

I have a little issue and it may be quite simple to fix. I need to Ghost some computers (locally) and now, it seems to be really hard to have several computers to boot from floppy. Sometimes the floppy is not detected (Old PC) and doesn't boot from it. So I need to create a Ghost image from a HDD.

I use Disk to Disk when ghosting from an IDE HDD but I'd like to change it to Disk from Image. My issue is it's a linux, IDE HDD, and I have a laptop with Windows 7. I also have a USB adaptor for IDE HDD. I'm trying to find a way to create a Bootable CD from the HDD connected on my laptop with the USB adaptor. Is it possible to do this? What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Bart PE bootable Windows PE CD](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/).

One of the BartPE plugins [lets you use Ghost](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/pluginhelp/ghost.htm) from the booted CD