# Create an ISO image of the current Windows 7 system?

Tags: windows, iso-image

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Free and easy alternatives to Ghost?](https://superuser.com/questions/99643/free-and-easy-alternatives-to-ghost)
>   [Windows backup by Imaging](https://superuser.com/questions/7739/windows-backup-by-imaging)

I was using Windows 7 image creating wizard, but it has created just a bunch of files. I need an ISO file of the current system, how can I get it?

Comment: Are you talking about creating a Windows 7 *installation* ISO, or an ISO of a currently installed Windows?

Comment: the second one - iso of a currently installed windows

Comment: What you want to do is make a *ghost* of the running system.  You can start with Clonezilla, DriveImage XML, or other programs.  See the questions I linked to in my comment below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free and easy alternatives to Ghost?](http://superuser.com/questions/99643/free-and-easy-alternatives-to-ghost) or [Disk Imaging Software](http://superuser.com/questions/18109/disk-imaging-software) or [Create a bootable Ghost CD from a HDD](http://superuser.com/questions/130106/create-a-bootable-ghost-cd-from-a-hdd)

Comment: Dont agree with duplication, he is asking about creating an image from the current partition that he is using his operational system

Comment: @Diogo_Rocha every single program in your answer has been mentioned in the questions I linked to above.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to create an image from your current system you will need to boot your machine from another partition that isn't the one that you want to save. So, I would reccomend you to create a bootable CD or pendrive with linux, Clonezilla or even WinPE. So, after you have booted from one of these options you can save your partition image. I think the best program to do that is [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org).